# Azure Data Factory error DFExecutorUserError error code 1204

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

So I am getting an error in Azure Data Factory that I haven't been able to find any information about.  I am running a data flow and eventually (after an hour or so) get this error

> {"StatusCode":"DFExecutorUserError","Message":"Job failed due to
> reason: The service has encountered an error processing your request.
> Please try again. Error code 1204.","Details":"The service has
> encountered an error processing your request. Please try again. Error
> code 1204."}

Troubleshooting I have already done :

1. I have successfully ran the data flow using the sample option.  Did this with 1 million rows.
2. I am processing 3 years of data and I have successfully processed all the data by filter the data by year and running the data flow once for each year.

So I think I have shown the data isn't the problem, because I have processed all of it by breaking it down into 3 runs.

I haven't found a pattern in the time the pipeline runs for before the error occurs that would indicate I am hitting any timeout value.

The source and sink for this data flow are both an Azure SQL Server database.

Does anyone have any thoughts?  Any suggestions for getting a more verbose error out of data factory (I already have the pipeline set with verbose logging).

Comment: Can you try  recreate the linked service and source?

Comment: I opened a Microsoft support ticket and they are saying it is a database transient caused failure.

Comment: Did they give any workarounds?

Comment: Hi @Rambis,  I'm glad to hear the you has find the root cause. I just help post this as answer. Hope you can accept it as answer(( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.)). This can be beneficial to other community members. if it's convenient, can you share us any workaround for this? Thank you!

Comment: The only thing they gave me was their BS article on handling transient errors. Maybe I’m just old but a database that cannot maintain connections to it is not very useful. 

What I’ve done to workaround this is increase my vCores. This sql database was a serverless one. While performance didn’t look bad my guess is the database must be doing some sort of resize in the background to handle the hour long data builds I need it to do. I had already tried setting the min/max vCores to be the same. The connection errors disappeared when I increased the vCores count to 6.

Comment: Hi @Rambis, please don't say that. Some times Microsoft engineers may don't have the same environment or have much experiences to deal with the error. The most important thing is that you have resolved it! I have updated to the answer. hope you can mark it and others can ref from you!

Comment: Hi @Rambis, do you have any other concerns? If you need, you can post it as answer and mark it. I will delete mine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We are glad to hear that you has found the cause:

- "I opened a Microsoft support ticket and they are saying it is a
  database transient caused failure."

I think the error will be resolved automatically. I post this as answer and this can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

**Update:**

The most important thing is that you have resolved it by increase the vCorces in the end.

- "The only thing they gave me was their BS article on handling
  transient errors. Maybe I’m just old but a database that cannot
  maintain connections to it is not very useful. What I’ve done to
  workaround this is increase my vCores. This sql database was a
  serverless one. While performance didn’t look bad my guess is the
  database must be doing some sort of resize in the background to
  handle the hour long data builds I need it to do. I had already tried
  setting the min/max vCores to be the same. The connection errors
  disappeared when I increased the vCores count to 6."