# Resolving error StatusCode":"DFExecutorUserError" 1204

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a dataflow that joins (by unique ID) 2 tables which are big (around 20 million rows each) and then stores them into a new table.
The pipeline just runs the dataflow mentioned and the settings are maxed out (256 cores as it is a lot of data).
But for some reason i get the error mentioned, is there a way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: If the answer was helpful , You can Accept it as an Answer, so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem

Answer (score 1):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65838369) by [Leon Yue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10549281/leon-yue), this error can be resolved by increasing number of cores. But as you mentioned, you already have 256 cores.

You can try below 2 workarounds.

1. You need to check compute type of Integration Runtime, it should be **compute** optimized.
2. Create different Integration Runtimes for debug and prod.

For more information you can go through this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VT_2ZV3a7Fc).